# PHP mysqli query: couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a db connection and check a table for existing data. However I recieve this error and I am unable to find the cause:

> **Warning**:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   **/usr/share/nginx/www/me/container/class_lib.php** on line
>   **33**
>  
>  **Warning**:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, null given in
>   **/usr/share/nginx/www/me/container/class_lib.php** on line
>   **97**

```
class dbHandler {

    static $dbObj          = null;
    protected $db_host     = 'localhost';       #db host
    protected $db_username = 'user';  #db username
    protected $db_password = 'password';        #db password
    protected $db_name     = 'db';  #db name

    function __construct()
    {
        # connect if not connected
        if(self::$dbObj === null)
        {
            self::$dbObj = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name)
            or die($this->dbObj->error);
        }

        mysqli_set_charset(self::$dbObj, "utf8");

    }

    // query: query the db
    public function query($query)
    {
        return self::$dbObj->query($query);
    }

}

/*
    class userLogin
    create user login
*/
class userLogin {

    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct($username, $password) {

        $this->_dbConn = new dbHandler();

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

    }

    public function verifyCredentials() {

        if($this->verifyUsername())
        {

        } else {

            exit;

        }

        if($this->verifyPassword())
        {

        } else {

            exit;

        }


    }

    private function verifyUsername() {

        if(!(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $this->username)))
        {

            return true;

        }

    }

    private function verifyPassword() {

        $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";
        $result = $this->_dbConn->query($query);
        $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        var_dump($row);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: also, any dump or print of $row returns NULL even though there is data in the tbl_user table.

Comment: Where do you create class instance?

Comment: I call the class outside of this class_lib by using

  $username  = $_POST['username'];
  $password  = $_POST['password'];
  
  $login = new userLogin($username, $password);
  $login->verifyCredentials();

Then I call the db handler inside the userLogin constructor.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` should be `mysqli` in verifyPassword function.

Comment: Still returns same errors and NULL.

Comment: @Martin you can't just change it to the word mysqli, the rest of your code is Object Orientated. You need to make that OO as well. IE `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in <b>/usr/share/nginx/www/me/container/class_lib.php</b> on line <b>97</b><br />

Comment: return self::$dbObj->query($query);

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937880/mysqliquery-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Answer (score 4):

All your wrapper is over a mysqli object oriented way, and suddenly you have this line?

```
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You have to use the fetch_assoc from the mysqli result object

```
$result->fetch_assoc()
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. However this returns <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in <b>/usr/share/nginx/www/me/container/class_lib.php</b> on line <b>97</b><br />

Comment: @Martin It seems like your query fails. Because query returns false. So try this: `if ($result) { $result->fetch_assoc() } `

Comment: Yes, it return false. How can this be? And no I do not use mysql anymore only mysqli.

Comment: I have removed it from the code. I now use $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: It's ok, scratch my last comment. Coffee hasn't kicked in yet @Martin

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is clearly failing. Why you have a function query to call a query I don't know but I have a feeling that is the route cause of your issue. You would be better off with something like this:

```
class dbHandler extends mysqli {

    protected $db_host     = 'localhost';       #db host
    protected $db_username = 'user';  #db username
    protected $db_password = 'password';        #db password
    protected $db_name     = 'db';  #db name

    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct($this->db_host, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
            if($this->connect_errno)
            {
                    trigger_error('Unable to connect to the database [' . $this->connect_errno . ']: ' . $this->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }

    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::close();
    }

}

/*
    class userLogin
    create user login
*/
class userLogin {

    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct($username, $password) {

        $this->_dbConn = new dbHandler();

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

    }

    public function verifyCredentials() {

        if($this->verifyUsername())
        {

        } else {

            exit;

        }

        if($this->verifyPassword())
        {

        } else {

            exit;

        }


    }

    private function verifyUsername() {

        if(!(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $this->username)))
        {

            return true;

        }

    }

    private function verifyPassword() {

        $query  = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user";
        $result = $this->_dbConn->query($query);
            if($this->_dbConn->errno)
            {
                trigger_error('Error fetching users from table. Query: ' . $query . '. Error: ' . $this->_dbConn->error);
                return false;
            }
            if($result->num_rows)
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    var_dump($row);
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: My code works when you use a root mysql login. How is that possible if my code is invalid?

Comment: @Martin I never said it was invalid, I said it was confusing and could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So... I never gave the mysql user from localhost any grants. Only from the remote LAN. Problemo solved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably  **you are closing** the connection too early? `DBConnect->close();`?

so, if you try to execute any query after that, you will get an error!