# Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error message

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Internal Evaluation Guide\action4.php on line 176

The connection with the database is ok

```
for ($i =1; $i <=$s; $i++){
    //echo $idb[$i];
    echo "<br>";
    if ($kind1 == 'braxyxronia'){
        $d[$i] = $_POST["delb".$i];
        if ($d[$i]=="del"){
            $quer_del="Delete from apotelesmata where id='$idb[$i]' and kind='$kind1'";
            //echo $quer_del; the string is ok
            $result = $db->query($quer_del); //line 176
        }
    //$id=$i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the connection really still open? http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.query.php#103422 Make sure you have not called `$db->close()` somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937880/mysqliquery-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysql` to fetch the result but the error is showing that you are using `mysqli`. Make sure which extension are you using.
Use

```
mysqli_query("your link", "you sql query");
```